# How to find median trajectory of a spiral movement?

Tags: average, computational-geometry, tracking, moving-average, spiral

Lets some objects make complex spiral moving in 3D and we have get their trajectories projected on a plane.

[image: Trajectories of spirally moving objects]

How to find a median trajectory of such movements and estimate the amplitudes of spirals?

I assume that this requires averaging the coordinates of the trajectories, then somehow finding the distances from the extreme points of the trajectories to the midline. But I don't know a concrete algorithm for this. Can someone suggest this algorithm?

By median trajectory I mean a line that ges between path waves, something like linew on a picture below.

[image]

Comment: `median trajectory` conditioned to what? the xy axis or the previously printed point? because to me seems that every step is being sampled from `[-90°, 90°]` and then draws from the last point with that angle

Comment: Median trajectory is a line that goes between the waves of the path, something like that.

Comment: I suppose you have an array of pair of points right?

Comment: Yes. A polyline with (x, y) coordinates of vertices. I've added an example of median trajectories.

Comment: yes, but just to have a "nice datastrcture" to work on, we can imagine it as an array or pair of points, so something like `[[x1, y1], [x2,y2], [[x2,y2], [x3,y3]], ...]`

Comment: and to me it seems that you are looking for some something like a "low pass filter", to remove the "high frequency noise"

Comment: Yew, may be it is - the "low pass filter". Could you suggests someones?

Comment: I would use **sliding average** ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for a Kalman filter, but this method is a little complicated.

A simpler one is a moving average, with a number of samples that covers as closes as possible to a full period (which you can estimate visually).

Regarding the distances, you can compute the shortest Euclidean distance of every point to the midline (using a line-to-segment function). This will yield an alternating plot, which you can smoothen with a moving maximum (rather than average) over a period.

Comment: I have thousands of samples, so it is impossible to visually estimate the periods of all of them. Are there other solution or is it possible to estimate the period automatically?

Comment: First try on a few samples to see if the method satisfies you.